# Single quotes is not displayed in output while concatenating strings along with single quotes in excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have strings in each column as like below

[image: Excel Data]

I used concatenate formula in excel as below

```
=A1&+B1&+C1&+D1&+E1&+F1&+G1&+H1&+I1&+J1&+K1&+L1
```

Output of the above formula is below
[image]
But the expected output is below
[image]
Please help. I need single single quotes between the string 143001000100317520150311600030104200003000000O using excel formula.

Comment: Excel uses `'` to denote that a value with a numeric first character is a string. So you need to double-up apostrophes so that Excel sees it. Try `SELECT CHAR(39) + SUBSTRING('14300...',17,9);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using columns `E1` and `G1` for single quotes, set the value of the cell to `="'"` (equals double quote single quote double quote) instead of just typing a single quote in the cell.

[image]